# console.log() lines are not matching up correctly in React Office Add-in

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I started work on my React add-in project for Excel yesterday and VSCode popped up with a recommendation to install 'Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger' extension. So I installed it, and ever since the lines in my console are not matching up to my VSCode `console.log()` lines....

Here's an example:

[image: console.log not working]

I'm not 100% the extension was the cause, however that was the last thing I remember doing before the issue started. I have since uninstalled the extension.

It seems like there is something going wrong in the compiling of the file .... but i'm not experienced enough to figure it out. Maybe a react expert will have some idea?

I've tried creating a new React project with `yo office` and the console log lines are fine.

Any help is seriously appreciated - debugging is a nightmare!! Thanks

Comment: Are you using a bundler like WebPack? Or a minifier? Either of those will change the line numbers so they no longer match the line numbers of the source files.

Comment: Webpack I believe. I havent changed anything since creating the project with `yo` - quick update: i've just got home and the log lines are fine on my laptop

Comment: React is not related to that. In the IDE you see a module while in the browser you deal with a bundled JS file generated from your modules.

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshot you see a log line in the module while in the web browser you deal the log line in the generated by the bundler (webpack) javascript file. In your IDE you deal with [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) that are bundled into a single JS file.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Do you know how i would go about "re-aligning" the generated bundler and my IDE?

Comment: I believe webpack is used in your solution. Try learning more about this tool.